# NET Core+React template - After replacing ReactJS UI project with a Typescript project, the backend and the UI open in separate tabs. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Tools: Visual Studio 2022, NET6 (and VSCode editor for client app)

I created a NET Core + ReactJS project from the available templates in Visual Studio 2022 (without HTTPS). I wanted to switch to Typescript, so I created a new Create React App Typescript project and replaced the template's ReactJS ClientApp with it. I run the app by just clicking the Run button in Visual Studio.

I noticed that:

- In the original ReactJS case, the server would redirect from the "Launching the SPA proxy..." page (see screenshot below) to the template's default UI page automatically within one tab.
- With the new React Typescript project, the I see two tabs (see screenshot below): One "Launching the SPA proxy..." page, and one Create React App default page (in localhost:3000). Also, it seems that the server keep trying to spin up new instances of the Client App.

[image]

**How can I fix these issues?**

The launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44863",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "MyProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5203",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing the port numbers here, but that did not help.

And what is the 44863 port for? I don't see any browser tabs with that port. Backend server opens in 5203, and the ReactJS one in 44467 (see screenshot in the description).

**EDIT:**

I changed the React app's port number in the .csproj from 44467 to 3000 `<SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:3000</SpaProxyServerUrl>`

Now the "Launching the SPA proxy..." correctly redirects to the React app URL, and the server stopped trying to spin up new instances of the React app. However, the second tab is still there; it opens up alongside (and at the same time as) the "Launching the SPA proxy..." tab in the browser. I am guessing that is because the server and UI projects are launched separately. How to make them launch as one app? (Screenshot below)

[(Screenshot) Still launching two tabs and two terminals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eaiT.png)

Comment: It looks like there is some command somewhere that is launching a web browser with a react url, I recommend searching for that url in your project file. Or do you have somewhere where you are making repeated calls?

Answer (score 1):

In the ClientApp directory created from the template, there is a .env file containing a single line:

```
BROWSER=none
```

Adding this file to the React Typescript app directory stops the second browser tab from being opened.